# Profile Fields disappear while using hook_civicrm_buildForm

Tags: civimember, profile

I am using hook_buildForm as follows:

```
function custom_changes_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Member_Form_Membership'){
    $form->_elements[2]->_label = t('Client');
    $form->_elements[4]->_label = t('Consultation Type');
  }
}
```

I have added Profile fields associated with Membership,when I alter the membership form as given above, the profile fields disappear

Comment: Why don't you use $form's getElement method to retrieve your elem and  later on call elem's setLabel method?